# Python Proxy Request Failed Connection

Tags: python, https, proxy, bots

Im trying to make a Strawpoll Bot. I found something on Git Hub and took it, but its not able to connect to a proxy server. Either i get a timeout or it says "Couldn´t connect to proxy". I took https proxy´s from a free list.

Its not my code its frome [here](https://github.com/Luis-Hebendanz/strawpoll-voting-bot)
My python skills are very limited

I hope someon can help me

This is the code or download to hole zip [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/to035zulj8xn9ax/strawpoll-voting-bot-master.zip?dl=0)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


try:
   from xml.dom import minidom
   import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
   from optparse import OptionParser
   import sys
   import os
except ImportError as msg:
  print("[-] Library not installed: " + str(msg))
  exit()

try:
  import requests except ImportError:
  print("[-] Missing library 'requests'")
  print("[*] Please install missing library with: pip install requests")

 # Creator: Luis Hebendanz
class Main:

# SETTINGS
maxVotes = 1
voteFor = ""
surveyId = ""

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
proxyListFile = "D:\Feko Karels\Documents\Informatik Kram\Python\strawpoll-voting-bot-master\https-proxy-list.xml"
saveStateFile = "saveState.xml"
proxyTimeout = 10 # Seconds
currentProxyPointer = 0
successfulVotes = 0

def __init__(self):
    try:

        ###
        # Command line argument parser
        ###
        parser = OptionParser()
        parser.add_option("-v", "--votes", action="store", type="string", dest="votes",help="number of votes to give")
        parser.add_option("-s", "--survey", action="store", type="string", dest="survey",help="id of the survey")
        parser.add_option("-t", "--target", action="store", type="string", dest="target", help="checkbox to vote for")
        parser.add_option("-f", "--flush", action="store_true", dest="flush",help="Deletes skipping proxy list")
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

        if len(sys.argv) > 2:
                if options.votes is None:
                    print("[-] Number of votes not defined with: -v ")
                    exit(1)
                if options.survey is None:
                    print("[-] Survey id not defined with: -s")
                    exit(1)
                if options.target is None:
                    print("[-] Target to vote for is not defined with: -t")
                    exit(1)
                try:
                    self.maxVotes = int(options.votes)
                except ValueError:
                    print("[-] Please define an integer for -v")

                # Save arguments into global variable
                self.voteFor = options.target
                self.surveyId = options.survey

                # Flush saveState.xml
                if options.flush == True:
                    print("[*] Flushing saveState.xml file...")
                    os.remove(self.saveStateFile)

        # Print help
        else:
            print("[-] Not enough arguments given")
            print()
            parser.print_help()
            exit()

        # Read proxy list file
        alreadyUsedProxy = False
        xmldoc = minidom.parse(self.proxyListFile)
        taglist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('para')
        tagList2 = None

        # Check if saveState.xml exists and read file
        if os.path.isfile(self.saveStateFile):
            xlmSave = minidom.parse(self.saveStateFile)
            tagList2 = xlmSave.getElementsByTagName("usedProxy")

        # Print remaining proxies
        if tagList2 is not None:
            print("[*] Number of remaining proxies in list: " + str(len(taglist) - len(tagList2)))
            print()
        else:
            print("[*] Number of proxies in new list: " + str(len(taglist)))
            print()

        # Go through proxy list
        for tag in taglist:

            # Check if max votes has been reached
            if self.successfulVotes >= self.maxVotes:
                break

            # Increase number of used proxy integer
            self.currentProxyPointer += 1

            # Read value out of proxy list
            tagValue = tag.childNodes[0].nodeValue

            # Read in saveState.xml if this proxy has already been used
            if tagList2 is not None:
                for tag2 in tagList2:
                    if tagValue == tag2.childNodes[0].nodeValue:
                        alreadyUsedProxy = True
                        break

            # If it has been used print message and continue to next proxy
            if alreadyUsedProxy == True:
                print("["+ str(self.currentProxyPointer) +"] Skipping proxy: " + tagValue)
                alreadyUsedProxy = False
                continue

            # Print current proxy information
            print("["+ str(self.currentProxyPointer) +"] New proxy: " + tagValue)
            print("[*] Connecting... ")

            # Connect to strawpoll and send vote
            self.sendToWebApi('https://' + tagValue)

            # Write used proxy into saveState.xml
            self.writeUsedProxy(tagValue)
            print()

        # Check if max votes has been reached
        if self.successfulVotes >= self.maxVotes:
            print("[+] Finished voting: " + str(self.successfulVotes))
        else:
            print("[+] Finished every proxy!")

        exit()
    except IOError as ex:
        print("[-] " + ex.strerror + ": " + ex.filename)

    except KeyboardInterrupt as ex:
        print("[*] Saving last proxy...")
        print("[*] Programm aborted")
        exit()


def getClientIp(self, httpProxy):
    proxyDictionary = {"https": httpProxy}
    rsp = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org/", proxies=proxyDictionary)
    return str(rsp.text)


def writeUsedProxy(self, proxyIp):
    if os.path.isfile(self.saveStateFile):
        # Read file
        tree =  ET.parse(self.saveStateFile)
        # Get <root> tag
        root = tree.getroot()
        child = ET.Element("usedProxy")
        child.text = str(proxyIp)
        root.append(child)
        # Write to file
        tree.write(self.saveStateFile, encoding="UTF-8")
    else:
        # Create <root> tag
        root = ET.Element("article")
        # Get element tree
        tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
        # Write to file
        tree.write(self.saveStateFile, encoding="UTF-8")

        # Now write defined entry into file
        self.writeUsedProxy(proxyIp)



def sendToWebApi(self, httpsProxy):
    try:
        headers = \
            {
                'Host': 'strawpoll.de',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en; q=0.3',
                'Referer': 'https://strawpoll.de/' + self.surveyId,
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'Content-Length': '29',
                'Cookie': 'lang=de',
                'DNT': '1',
                'Connection': 'close'
            }
        payload = {'pid': self.surveyId, 'oids': self.voteFor}
        proxyDictionary = {"https": httpsProxy}

        # Connect to server
        r = requests.post('https://strawpoll.de/vote', data=payload, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDictionary, timeout=self.proxyTimeout) #
        json = r.json()

        # Check if succeeded
        if(bool(json['success'])):
            print("[+] Successfully voted.")
            self.successfulVotes += 1
            return True
        else:
            print("[-] Voting failed. This Ip already voted.")
            return False

    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as ex:
        print("[-] Timeout")
        return False

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as ex:
        print("[-] Couldn't connect to proxy")
        return False

    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
        return False

# Execute main
Main()
```

Comment: Did you follow the step in the README ?

Comment: yes of course i did